# Help on if I'm using such correctly

Tags: such

I was wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct:

> I am not glad. Such is the sentiment of fools.

Am I using *such* correctly here? I spent a good hour researching its use and couldn't find what I was looking for. I thought that perhaps someone on here could provide me with the answer I seek.

Comment: Yes, *such* is a pronoun there. How it summarizes being glad or not glad, I don't know.

Comment: It's grammatical, but as Yosef goes on to say, unclear (is it referring to gladness or 'my' not being glad?) and some would say thus unacceptable as it violates the Gricean maxim of manner. It could be marked down in an essay.

Comment: As the above have said, it's grammatical but ambiguous and confusing. It could mean that being glad is the sentiment of fools, so you're not a fool because you're not glad. Or it could mean that you're a fool because you're not glad.

Comment: Thank you for your answers–they’re very helpful. I guess I should have provided more context. I’m writing a book, and this is something one of my characters say. He’s a bit of a pessimist. The character he’s talking to says “Aren’t you glad?” and he responds with that. So he’s essentially saying only fools are glad.